# Distribution and parameters after transformation

Tags: correlation, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution

Let $X\sim(m_X,\sigma_X^2)$ and $Y\sim(m_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$. We know that both $X$ and $Y$ are more like lognormal than normal.

Also, Pearson correlation coefficient is known: $\rho=r(X,Y)$.

We have the decay formula $\ f(X,Y)=X\ exp(a\ Y^b)$, where $a<0$ and $-1<b<0$.

Is it likely, that $f$ will have "lognormal-like" distribution? If yes, what is the best estimate for it's parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ expressed as function of $m_X$, $\sigma_X^2$, $m_Y$, $\sigma_Y^2$ and $\rho$? If no, what is the best way to approximate $E(f)$, $Var(f)$? In both cases, the Pearson-correlation $r(f,Y)$ would also be needed.

Comment: @Glen_b $p$ is usually $0.25$, $0.4$ or $0.6$ so not really close to zero. How about estimating the after-transformation statistics and correlation? I'm aware of Taylor-expansion (first-order method). Are ther other ones, too?

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are close to lognormal, their logs will be close to normal.

Now $\log(f) = \log(X) + aY^p$ where $p=-b$ is between $0$ and $1$.

*If* $p$ is close to $0$ then the transformation of $Y$ will be "like" a log transform (consider the Box-Cox family, where as $\lambda\to 0$, $\frac{y^\lambda-1}{\lambda} = \frac{1}{\lambda}Y^\lambda - \frac{1}{\lambda}$ goes to $\log y$. Hence $aY^p = ap .(\frac{1}{p}Y^p - \frac{1}{p})+a$ will (if $p$ is close to $0$ behave like $ap \log(Y) + a$.

If $p$ is close to $1$ it will be more like a rescaling of $Y$, leaving a result again close to lognormal. So there you'd be adding something like a normal and something like a lognormal.

So in the event that $p$ is close to $0$, so that $f$ will be something like a sum of two normals, will $f$ be close to normal?

Not in general. Simply having normal margins with some correlation doesn't make the sum close to normal.

So on the information given we have no basis on which to think $f$ will behave like a normal for any value of $b$ in the range, even when $aY^b$ would be reasonably close to normal.